# NSString enumerateSubstringsInRange not iterating as expected

Tags: ios, unicode, nsstring, emoji

I'm trying to parse a string in iOS that may contain Emojis, but for some Emojis I've noticed that it's not giving me the entire character.

Here's an example with the US flag character:

```
NSString *text = @""; // Unicode: U+D83C U+DDFA U+D83C U+DDF8
[text enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange( 0, text.length )
                         options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                           usingBlock:^( NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop ) {
                               NSLog( @"%@", substring );
                           }];
```

Output:

Comment: Btw. strings in Apple's new programming language Swift can handle this correctly, compare https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html.

Comment: Hey Martin thanks for linking the Delete question, but has the UITextInputTokenizer actually been proven to work? I can't seem to find any resources online demonstrating it, so this question may serve as an opportunity to offer some sort of example using UITextInputTokenizer.

Comment: It looked like the same problem to me and has an accepted answer, therefore I closed it as a duplicate. I did not verify the answer. If someone finds a better solution then it can be posted as an answer to the other question.

Comment: Added a solution to that question, but even that one isn't perfect. Hopefully someone can improve upon it or say what the issue is.